# Laplace transform with (real) compact support

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform

Given the standard unilateral Laplace transform defined on $L^1(\mathbb R ^+)$
$$ \mathscr Lf(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)~dt,$$

are there any functions in $L^1$ such that $\mathscr Lf$ is "compactly supported", where with compact support I mean that there exists an $M >0$ such that  $$\mathscr Lf(s) = 0 \quad\text{if}\ \operatorname{Re} s > M.$$

Comment: $f\equiv 0$. (Sorry, just being a dick.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because $\tilde f(z) = \int e^{-zt}f(t)dt, Re(z) > 0$  is an analytic function of z and so is not going to vanish on any set with a limit.